# When using useState hook, typescript complains about type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
const [state, setState] = useState<string[]>([]);

const deleteItem = (item: string) => {
    let newItem: string[] = [];
    setState((prev) => {
        newItem = [...prev];
        newItem.splice(newItem.indexOf(item), 1);
        setState(newItem);
        return newItem;
    });
};
```

Typescript gives an error to (prev):
`Argument of type '(prev: any) => string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.`

Comment: what is the  type of `prev` ?

Comment: For me it compiles properly. But I noticed that calling `setState(newItem)` inside `setState((prev) => {...})` is unnecessary and can lead to bugs. What you return from the setter function will be set to `state` by react, so no need to call `setState` again.

Comment: Prev is previous value of state. Type is string[]

Comment: Where are you getting `(prev: any) => string[]`, beacuse on type inferance `prev` will be string[] not any

Answer (score 1):

What about more straightforward approach? [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will create a new array, omitting the values predicates returns `false` for.

```
const deleteItem = (itemToRemove: string) => {
  setState((previous) => {
    return previous.filter(item => item !== itemToRemove);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not set the state again inside the setState as you are already returning the updated state value based on the previous state.
Update the delete function as

```
const deleteItem = (item: string) => {
    let newItem: string[] = [];
    setState((prev) => {
      newItem = [...prev];
      newItem.splice(newItem.indexOf(item), 1);
      return newItem;
    });
  };
```

Also try to use meaningful names as state variable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do setState inside another setState.

An even simpler solution in addition to @NeERaJ TK's answer.

```
const deleteItem = (item: string) =>
  setState(prev => prev.filter(currItem => currItem !== item));
```